# how to fix border issue in html5

Tags: css, html

This is my html5 code for footer:

```
        <footer>
            <div class="footer">

            <nav class="footer-nav">
                <ul class="list-1">
                    <li><img src="img/notes.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li>ARTICLES</li>
                    <li>COLUMNS</li>
                    <li>BLOG</li>
                    <li>TOPICS</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-2">
                    <li>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>AUTHORS</li>
                    <li>MASTHEAD</li>
                    <li>CONTRUBUTE</li>
                    <li>STYLE GUIDE</li>
                    <li>CONTACT</li>
                    <li>SPONSORSHIPS</li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
            <hr class="hr-style">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-left">
                <img src="img/footer1.png" alt="footer-image" />

                <p class="footer-title">.NET Training</p>
<p class="footer-pgf">Less of boring theory! Hands on programming is our training methodology! You'll love it.<p>
<a href="#">learn more </a>
                </div>

                <div class="footer-right">
                    <img src="img/footer2.png" alt="footer-image" />

                    <p class="footer-title">Shopify Expert at $20/hour</p>
<p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made shopify theme and tweakss. Strat selling online with stunning eCommerce storefronts created using the Shopify CMS</p>
<a href="#">learn more</a>  

                </div>
        </div>
                <hr class="hr-style">

                <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
                </div>
                </footer>
```

and css:

```
.footer{
    clear:both;
    background:url('../img/footer-bg.jpg');
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-left{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer-right{
    float:right;    
    width:50%;
}
.footer-nav .list-1 {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav .list-2 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding:8px;
}
img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.copyright{
    font-size:13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-left:after,.footer-right:after{

    clear:both;
    content: "";

}
.row{}
```

In footer i added `<hr />` two places, such as top of footer content and top of footer copyright, but it shows only in top footer-content.

What is my mistake, please help me.

This is JSfiddle link what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/14/

Comment: Your HTML is not well-formed. Check your fiddle, the offending tags are marked in red. Unfortunately, that's just the first of your problems, but it will discourage people from looking further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a clear both div

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

inside the

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="footer-left">...</div>
        <div class="footer-right">...</div>
</div>
```

Please see the JSFiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.footer
{
    clear:both;
    background:url('../img/footer-bg.jpg');
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-left
{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer-right
{
    float:right;    
    width:50%;
}
.footer-nav .list-1 
{
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav .list-2 
{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav ul li
{
    display:inline;
    padding:8px;
}
img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.copyright
{
    font-size:13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-left:after,.footer-right:after
{

    clear:both;
    content: "";

}
.a
{
    width:500;
    float:left;

}
.row{}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:1000;margin:0 auto;">
     <header>
            <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/tvw52r1ux/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
                <h1>The Articles</h1>
                    <nav class="header-nav">    
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s12.postimg.org/hyaxg6xah/icon.png" alt="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>          
    </header>
        <section id="section">
            <div class="a">
                <article class="article">
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/7l8a2s4kp/articles.jpg" alt="articles" />
                        <p class="comments">by<span class="woo"> JOHN WOO</span> 
                        <date>June 04, 2013, 22 Comments</date></p>
                        <h1 class="issue">Issue No 376</h1>
                        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consectetur adipising elit Vestibulum eu ligula justo, ullamcorper viverraest. Donec viverra libero in tellus ullamcorper lobortis,. Nam nunc metus, molestie sit amet sagitis et, hendrenit quam. Ut hendrerit commodo nunc, eu euismod odio egestas a. Morbi felis lorem, convallis id scelerisque eget, faucibus eget lectus.</p>
                        <p class="dev-express">asp.net, .net, dev-express</p>
                        <a href="#" class="myButton">More</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/dnfwt9t0p/cat.png" alt="" />
                        <p class="comments">by <span class="woo">JOHN WOO</span> <date>June 04, 2013, 22 Comments</date></p>
                        <h1 class="issue">Issue No 375</h1>
                        <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consectetur adipising elit Vestibulum eu ligula justo, ullamcorper viverraest. Donec viverra libero in tellus ullamcorper lobortis,. Nam nunc metus, molestie sit amet sagitis et, hendrenit quam. Ut hendrerit commodo nunc, eu euismod odio egestas a. Morbi felis lorem, convallis id scelerisque eget, faucibus eget lectus.</p>
                        <p class="dev-express">asp.net, .net, dev-express</p>
                        <a href="#" class="myButton">More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="a">
            <aside class="aside" style="margin:0 0 0 200;">
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/51cn8oh0p/agencies.jpg" alt="agencies" />
                <h3>From the Blog</h3>
                <p class="windows">DAVID  <i> on </i>c# Windows</p>
                <p class="hex">How to convert System.Color to HTML color (hex)?</p>
                <p class="sidebar-pgf">I'm working on an application that requires converting the back color of the panel to HTML that can be used as a div background color. Please help.</p>
                <a class="view" href="#">view answer</a>
            </aside>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
           <div class="footer">
            <nav class="footer-nav">
                <ul class="list-1">
                    <li><img src="http://s18.postimg.org/4xe8eom5h/notes.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li>ARTICLES</li>
                    <li>COLUMNS</li>
                    <li>BLOG</li>
                    <li>TOPICS</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-2">
                    <li>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>AUTHORS</li>
                    <li>MASTHEAD</li>
                    <li>CONTRUBUTE</li>
                    <li>STYLE GUIDE</li>
                    <li>CONTACT</li>
                    <li>SPONSORSHIPS</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <hr class="hr-style">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/itr24b7s9/footer1.png" alt="footer-image" />
                    <p class="footer-title">.NET Training</p>
                    <p class="footer-pgf">Less of boring theory! Hands on programming is our training methodology! You'll love it.<p>
                    <a href="#">learn more </a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-right">
                    <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/gl8a98bah/footer2.png" alt="footer-image" />
                    <p class="footer-title">Shopify Expert at $20/hour</p>
                    <p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made shopify theme and tweakss. Strat selling online with stunning eCommerce storefronts created using the Shopify CMS</p>
                    <a href="#">learn more</a>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr-style">
            <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```